# Python reshape array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very unique error I feel. I am working with an array 'A' of shape

```
>>> A.shape
(1L, 1823L, 24L)
```

I am trying to get rid of first dimension as it is empty. So, I do something as:

```
>>> z1 = A[0,:,:]
>>> z1.shape
(1253L,)
>>> z1[0].shape
()
>>> z1[0]
10411.505889359611
```

I don't understand where this 1253 is coming from. I tried to use other simple examples and it works fine for smaller arrays.

I also tried squeeze as:

```
import numpy as np
>>> z2 = np.squeeze(A,0)
>>> z2.shape
(1253L,)
```

My ultimate goal is to make a vector out of elements of array 'A' such that after squeezing A to dimension 1823x24, I gather the elements from rows wise order.

Edit: My code should have worked too but the temporary variable I was using for the process wasn't changing for some reason. I tried deleting the temporary variable and still won't go away. So, I created a new temporary variable and it worked. I am using Pycharm so I am not sure where the issue was coming from.

Comment: Are you sure you're not messing some other thing up?
`np.random.random((1,1823,24))[0,:,:].shape` returns `(1823L, 24L)` for me.

Comment: That makes no sense. Are you sure the `A` for which you're printing `A.shape` and the `A` for which you're doing `A[0,:,:]` are the same `A`? Can you show us `type(A)` and `A.dtype`?

Comment: Yes I scratched my head off over this. But that is how it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.reshape()` for this.

Example [from the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
>>> a = np.arange(6).reshape((3, 2))
>>> a
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
```

In your example, this would be:

```
A.reshape((1823, 24))
```

Comment: In theory, that should work, but so should the code the questioner posted.